# Highcharter StyledMode gradients

Tags: highcharts, r-highcharter

Trying to build a chart with gradient fill in Highcharter for R, when **styledMode** is enabled.

In highchart zones are defined using 'defs', but there is no equivalent in the Highcharter R package.

Appreciate any input

JS example: https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/css/gradient/

Docs:
https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/gradients-shadows-and-patterns

Small shiny example (defs missing)

```
library(shiny)
library(highcharter)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  tags$link(rel="stylesheet", type = "text/css",href = 'https://code.highcharts.com/css/highcharts.css'),
  
  tags$style(HTML("
  /* solid color */
  .highcharts-color-0 {
    fill: green;
    stroke:green;
   }
   
   /* how it should work
   .highcharts-color-0 {
    fill: url(#gradient-0);
    stroke:url(#gradient-0);
   }
 */
")),
  highchartOutput("columnChart")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$columnChart <- renderHighchart({
    # Create the column chart with gradient bars
    highchart() %>%
      hc_chart(styledMode=T) %>%
      hc_xAxis(categories = c("Category 1", "Category 2", "Category 3")) %>%
      hc_add_series(
        type= 'column',
        name = "Data",
        data = c(10, 15, 7)
      )
    # defs missing
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: As of my knowledge Highcharter, the R package for Highcharts, does not fully support defs and styled mode, which are needed to create gradients in JavaScript example. That being said, I encourage you to reach out to the maintainers of the Highcharter package. The limitations of the Highcharter package may change as it is updated over time. Here I see that it has already been reported, you can give a thumbs up to draw attention to this matter: https://github.com/jbkunst/highcharter/issues/799